# How to get accessibility display setting

Tags: android, accessibility

Does anyone know how to get accessibility display setting?
Those settings includes grayscale mode, color adjustment, etc.
I cannot find any ways to do with Setting.Secure.getString() and AccessibilityManager.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        Intent mAccessibleIntent =
        new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(mAccessibleIntent);
```

Comment: Oh it doesn't work. I just want to know if those settings are enabled or not.

Comment: what's your phone ,i tested on genymotion  and it worked

Comment: This is the Galaxy S7. Can you share your full code? I think I did something wrong.

Comment: there's no other code, i'm using Galaxy S7 myself too..and it also works ,that's really weird ,  do you get any err ?